# AWS hyperledger fabric services is it available for Mumbai, India location

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, amazon-managed-blockchain

AWS is supporting the blockchain hyperledger fabric technology services.
But my question is it available for Mumbai, India location?

Answer (score 1):

> Q: What region is the Amazon Managed Blockchain preview currently
>   available in?
>
> A: The Amazon Managed Blockchain preview is currently available in US.
>   East (N. Virginia). It will be available in more regions soon.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/managed-blockchain/faqs/

Answer (score 0):

Mumbai support (BOM) is not yet implemented but on the roadmap.